# Density estimation in Python

Tags: python, statistics, kernel-density

I'm new to Python and I have to estimate a density from a 2D sample. My first idea was a simple histogram estimator, which I implemented as below:

```
num = 10**4
sp = 0.01

subsetf1 = np.random.uniform(0,1,size=(num,2)) # I created this set to test the estimator

def f_est(x,y,h=sp, subset=subsetf1):
    indicator = np.zeros(num)

    for i in range(num):
        if (x <= subset[i][0] <= (x + h)) and (y <= subset[i][1] <= (y + h)):
            indicator[i] = 1
        else :  indicator[i] = 0


    return sum(indicator)/(num*h**2)

#f_est should yield values closely to 1 if  0 <x,y <1 , because  subsetf1 contains uniformly distributed values on [0,1).
```

The problem is that `f_est` often yields values greater than 1 which leads me to believe that my code is wrong, but I don't know where the bug could be. I also tried kernel density estimation but if I try something like:

```
from scipy import stats
xmin = partsetf1[0].min()
xmax = partsetf1[0].max()
ymin = partsetf1[1].min()
ymax = partsetf1[1].max()
X, Y = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:100j, ymin:ymax:100j]
positions = np.vstack([X.ravel(), Y.ravel()])
values = np.vstack([partsetf1[0], partsetf1[1]])
gkde=stats.gaussian_kde(values)
f = np.reshape(gkde(positions).T, X.shape)
```

f yields strange values which can't be right. 
It would be great if someone could tell me where the bug in my code is and maybe how to use kde in Python, because I did not find good tutorials on this topic.

Comment: Have you compared your results with built in functions like scipy's density estimation? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html

Or rather, I should ask, to what have you compared your results to, if anything?

Comment: Hi @Jon . I also tried scipy's density estimation, the code therefore is also in my post. The problem is scipys densitys estimation yields utterly wrong results and I don't know why

Comment: Sorry, I did not see that. An alternative to Scipy, is statsmodels. Have you tried this http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/notebooks/generated/statsmodels.nonparametric.kde.KDEUnivariate.html?highlight=kde#statsmodels.nonparametric.kde.KDEUnivariate

Answer (score 0):

Kernel density estimates can produce values greater than 1 because they are not returning a *probability*, but rather a *probability density*. A probability density in your case gives the probability per unit area, and can locally be much larger than 1.

The good news is that since your results match that of scipy or statsmodels, it sounds like your code is correct.